# Undoing a bunch of Git mess

Tags: git

I want to revert back to a specific commit ID. Restore a file I "git rm"-ed. Blow away all commits made since then. And then commit that repo. How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ git reset --hard <commit ID>    # Will reset to a specific commit
$ git push -f <remote>            # Push branch into remote, with force
```

Note that anyone who has cloned your repo may experience minor problems if they simply pull in your changes (since you forced the branch backwards in the commit history); they should do this to get your changes:

```
$ git fetch <remote>
$ git reset --hard <remote>/<branch>
```

Note that this will also blow away any of *their* changes in the current branch. However, if they have any branches made from their current branch, those branches will still have the commits you "blew away".

Comment: There are some people thinking that `push -f` is a crime!

Comment: It's useful in some circumstances, if you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for `git reset --soft {ID}`.

```
   git reset --<mode> [<commit>]
       This form resets the current branch head to <commit> and possibly updates the index (resetting it to the tree of <commit>) and the working tree depending on <mode>, which must be one of the
       following:

       --soft
           Does not touch the index file nor the working tree at all (but resets the head to <commit>, just like all modes do). This leaves all your changed files "Changes to be committed", as git
           status would put it.
```

Not sure what 'blow" really means, that why `--hard` mode could be useful too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **git revert my_commit_id** command.

If it is one or two previous commits, you do it with `git revert HEAD` and `git revert HEAD^` respectively.

Instead of HEAD use your commit id if this doesnt solve your case.

This will also give you an option to edit commit messg again and create new commit.
`